# Data Mapper — какие классы за что отвечают?

Tags: архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, data-mapper

Где проходят границы между зонами ответственности классов при использовании паттерна [Data Mapper](http://www.design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-mapper.html)?

Если я правильно понимаю логику паттерна, таких классов как минимум три: собственно маппер, объект предметного слоя и [репозиторий](http://www.design-pattern.ru/patterns/repository.html). И если с разделением базовых (CRUD) задач всё понятно, то **не понятно, какой класс должен отвечать за поиск**.

Допустим, в маппере есть метод *find()*, который по идентификатору находит нужную запись и возвращает готовый объект предметного слоя. Это в теории, а в практике в реальных системах условий поиска гораздо больше: модель оборудования можно искать не только по идетификатору, но и (к примеру) по производителю, категории, стоимости, дате производства.

Ситуация сильно усложняется, если атрибуты в объекте предметного слоя отличаются в написании от названий полей в базе данных (например, *producerId* в коде и *producer_id* в БД).

Ну и еще более ситуация усложнится, если в системе есть несколько родственных объектов и используется [наследование с единой таблицей](http://www.design-pattern.ru/patterns/single-table-inheritance.html). Маппер спокойно берет название класса из БД с прочими данными и генерирует тот или иной объект.

**Итак, о поиске.** Получается, нужно создавать еще один класс, который будет отвечать за поиск? А если маппер возвращает один из трёх возможных объектов, то таких классов должно быть уже три?

Подпните, пожалйста в нужную сторону.

Comment: DataMapper  просто маппит данные на объекты. У вас скорее проблема "как организовать слой доступа к данным, а то столько разных паттернов".

Comment: @vitidev, DataMapper, оборажает DomainObject на хранилище. Причем это _двухстороннее_ отображение. Как следствие, место реализации методов выборки объектов из хранилища имеет принципиальное значение.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а я что сказал?

Answer (score 3):

Советую в первую очередь посмотреть в сторону уже готовых решений: *Doctrine* для `PHP` и *Hibernate* для `Java`, также к прочтению: **"Шаблоны корпоративных приложений" М.Фаулера** - классический труд, раздел про паттерны объектно-реляционного отображения - весь Ваш.

Теперь, понятное дело, что в коротком ответе я не смогу Вам передать в двух словах содержание целого раздела книги и выводы из ознакомления с исходниками *Doctrine*, но "подтолкнуть" попробую :)

Во-первых, результаты поиска клиенту выдают либо Mapper, либо Repository. Кто именно - зависит от реализации и точки зрения, единого правильного ответа здесь нет. Создавать отдельный класс, который будет отвечать только за поиск не надо, но иногда стоит выделить отдельный интерфейс (например,  `ProductFinder`), который будет относиться к пакету предметной области и, который будет реализован в классах пакета доступа к данным (в Ваших мапперах). Т.е. классы предметной области будут знать об интерфейсе поиска, но не будут зависить от конкретной реализации.

Во-вторых, в мапперах можно определить кроме `find()` методы тз серии `findBy(array $criteria)`, которые могут решать частные задачи поиска. Задачу с несовпадением названий колонок и полей - мапперы должны решать, исходя из своей конфигурации или отталкиваясь от метаданных. Одна из задач маппера - сделать Ваши объекты независимыми от структуры хранения данных. К слову, для полноценной реализации методов `findBy` и пр. подобных - Вам необходимо в том или ином виде реализовать паттерн *Specification*. К слову, цитата из Фаулера (не точная): "*реализация паттернов Repository и Specification зачастую содержит значительную часть реализации объектной базы данных*", что в целом должно лишний раз подтолкнуть к тому, что лучше взять готовое (а главное проверенное) решение.

Про наследование: преобразователь должен знать какую сущность на какую таблицу он преображает. В целом, опять же советую посмотреть как эта задача решается в том же *Hibernate*.

**UPD**

*Правильно ли я понимаю, что дата маппер предполагает одну сущность = одной таблице (это даже в ответе, в последнем абзаце видно)?*

Неправильно.

Это комплексный вопрос и разбираться с ним стоит, беря за теоретическую базу не последний абзац моего ответа (в котором, как я упомянул уже, я не смогу полностью раскрыть тему при всем желании), а хотя бы упомянутую в первом абзаце книгу **М.Фаулера** (которую всяко полезно почитать любому разработчику).

Если коротко, то *Data Mapper* - это частный случай паттерна *Mapper*. Мотивация к его применению: сделать бизнес-логику максимально независимой от структуры хранения данных в *источнике данных*.

Обратите внимание на словосочетание *источник данных* (*Data Source*, если хотите). Если Вы будете мыслить абстрактной концепцией *источника данных*, то сможете увидеть, что таблица в базе - это всего лишь его частный случай. Но стоит заметить, что этот частный случай покрывает 95% задач разработчиков современных приложений, поэтому большинство разработчиков библиотек и пакетов, делает упор именно на него. Но. Опять же, таблица в базе - всего навсего частный случай источника данных. Соответственно, Вы можете написать шлюз к другому источнику данных - например, можно рассматривать **результат выполнения запроса**, как источник данных - с которым будет работать Ваш преобразователь(маппер).

К слову, не знаю насколько это подходит под Ваш случай, но можно в базе данных создать *view*, и работать с ним как с таблицей, если нужно *чтение* данных (с записью, скорее всего, при любых особо простого или общего решения добиться не получится для ситуаций, когда одна сущность собирается из множества таблиц - придется либо прописывать в каждом маппере руками логику обратного преобразования полей в данные и отправки соответствующих данных на свой источник данных для записи, либо организововать хитрую логику преобразования на основе метаданных). Плюс не могу не заметить, что если одна сущность не маппится на одну таблицу, то может это все таки повод рассматривать ее как композицию других сущностей, каждая из которых маппится на свою таблицу и обладает своим интерфейсом и логикой, а общая сущность будет являться неким "оркестратором" для работы со своими членами, предоставляя интерфейс более высокого уровня.

Еще раз советую: купите-скачайте и почитайте Фаулера, если хотите действительно разобраться в вопросе. Из отрывков коротких ответов на SO у Вас не сложится красивая структурированная полочка последовательных знаний по такому комплексному вопросу. Более того (и судя по вопросу *"маппер = таблица?"*, это уже в той или иной мере происходит), из этих отрывков у Вас может сложится верная в отдельных частях, но не верная в целом картина понимания по этому (стоит заметить очень важному для всякого разработчика ориентированного на enterprise) вопросу.

Вот Вам в качестве бонуса немного ссылок по Доктрине, может помогут:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741318/mapping-two-tables-to-one-entity-in-doctrine2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037626/symfony2-map-entity-to-different-tables

Comment: Во втором абзаце вы говорите о Doctrine, а в последнем о Hibernate. Несостыковочка.

Comment: В тексте ответа и Doctrine, и Hibernate приводятся как примеры проверенных решений, которые я советую Вам посмотреть. Где тут "несостыковачка"? Если что-то непонятно - спрашивайте-уточняйте, по возможности дополню ответ.

Comment: Несостыковочка в выражениях, которыми вы пользуетесь. Фраза "_В целом, опять же советую_" как бы намекает, что о Hibernate уже идет речь выше по тексту. Но нет. Хотя я, конечно, придираюсь =)

Comment: в первом абзаце советовал, т.ч. речь действительно шла) учитывая, что вы не указали на каком языке вас интересует реализация, посчитал, что будет полезным привести несколько примеров из разных языков. а общие принципы можно подсмотреть и там, и там.

Comment: Читаю, смотрю исходники и первое, что бросается в глаза, — проекция сущностей на таблицы. Правильно ли я понимаю, что дата маппер предполагает одну сущность = одной таблице (это даже в ответе, в последнем абзаце видно)? Пусть так. Ок. Но что делать, если в БД одна сущность размазана по нескольким таблицам? Ну не люблю я EAV, вот и приходится делить данные. $tableName в Doctrine очень в этом отношении настораживает.

Comment: дополнил ответ. я так понял, что речь у вас идет все таки про пхп разработку - можете посмотреть еще Spot ORM, он проще доктрины, но основан на ее dbal

Comment: Игорь, спасибо за расширенный ответ. Фаулер у меня есть. Раздел по работе с БД я перечитал и вдоль и поперек уже несколько раз. Меня не покидает ощущение, что помимо идеи отрыва объекта домена от поставщика данных из книги взять практически нечего. Вот в классе PersonMapper я вижу методы findByLastName() и findByLastName2 (!) Жесть? Жесть. А если мне нужно искать не только по фамилии, но и по городу рождения? Допускаю, что есть паттерны и для этого, но отсылок на такой кейс в тексте главы не вижу (при том, что книга прямо пестрит перекрестными ссылками).

Comment: ну вы же сами понимаете, что Фаулер не пошаговое руководство по написанию универсальной ORM делал)) Ваш кейс - это комплексное применение паттернов *Specification, Repository и Data Mapper*. Задача не простая - соответственно, единого решения у нее нету. Что могу посоветовать: если Вы это все не из академического интереса спрашиваете, а ищете решения для продакшна - не вздумайте писать велосипед, это не окупится.